# How to configure Yii2 component to use op_cache?

Tags: caching, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-5.5, yii-components

Yii2 documentation suggests the following configuration which is applicable for memCache.

```
    'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => 'server1',
                'port' => 11211,
                'weight' => 100,
            ],

        ],
    ],
 ]
```

1. How can i configure the component to use op_cache?
2. Where can i find the 'host','port','weight' information on a local WAMP server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The goal of [Opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) is not to store data, you cannot use it as a Yii2 data caching component :

> OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request.

You should read this : [Supported Cache Storage in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#supported-cache-storage).

Comment: Thanks Soju. I want to use php_apc cache in my Yii2 app but my php is 5.5+ so i can't use it. What could be the alternative way i can use php_apc or similar ? Thanks